# Parsing JSON response data in React action

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, promise, redux

I'm making a call to my server to get some json data from a 3rd party API (Yelp). I'm using axios and redux-promise to set the state in redux so I can use it in react. The data that gets returned is confusing me.

I want to set the state to an array of business data returned from the Yelp API. Currently, this action works if I pass in a basic string as the payload. I'm not sure how I get this JSON data from the api response and then manipulate it in react from the redux state.

## Here is what the data looks like

[image]

## Here is my action js file

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const ZIP_CODE = 'ZIP_CODE';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://www.localhost:3000/v1/location/1/1/2/4000'


function getBusinesses(json) {  
    const business_data = json['data']['businesses']
    console.log(business_data)
    return business_data;
}


/*
 * Updates the users location
*/
export function updateZip(zipCode) {

    const request = axios.get(ROOT_URL)
    .then(getBusinesses)
    
    return {
        type: ZIP_CODE,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

Comment: `The data that gets returned is confusing me` - in what way?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not sure how to correctly pass it to the payload. I pass it to the payload and the final result is a promise object.. I built the function to return just the array of items, but still nothing

Comment: yeah, however `updateZip` is called would have to be able to handle the fact that `payload` is a promise - beyond me I'm afraid, don't know enough about redux and reduc-promise to help. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for my solution which involved some awkward tinkering and fixing bugs on my end.

## Fix 1 - Updating the store

I've added thunk and it works well

```
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
  ));
```

## Fix 2 - Integration of thunk into action

I parsed the json in an intial function then returned it to the action that gets sent to the reducer

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const ZIP_CODE = 'ZIP_CODE';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://www.localhost:3000/v1/location/1/1/2/4000'

function getBusinesses(res) {   

    return {
        type: ZIP_CODE,
        payload: res['data']['businesses']
    }
}

export function updateZip(zipCode) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(ROOT_URL)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(getBusinesses(response))
      })
  }
}
```